# AngularJS : ng-bind-html inside a uib-tooltip-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have to show a tooltip in my UI. I am using angularjs in UI side.

Please see the code below.

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle f18 darkgray hover pointer" uib-tooltip-html="'<div class=fw-600>Reason:</div>"+obj.comments+"'" tooltip-class="white-blue-tooltip"></i>
```

But I am getting error when the value of `obj.comments = Canceled via 'View Group'`. Please see the error below.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'View' is an unexpected token at column 49 of the expression ['<div class=fw-600>Reason:</div>cancelling via 'View Group''] starting at [View Group''].
```

This is because of the single quote present in the value (Canceled via 'View Group').

In order to solve this I have used `ng-Sanitize` as described in the following link
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp

Now my code look like below

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle f18 darkgray hover pointer" uib-tooltip-html="'<div class=fw-600>Reason:</div> ng-bind-html="+obj.comments+"'" tooltip-class="white-blue-tooltip"></i>
```

But I am getting output like

```
Reason: 
ng-bind-html=Canceled via 'View Group'
```

I have added `'ngSanitize'` in my controller and loaded the `angular.min.js` and `angular-sanitize.js` in the page, is there anything missing here.

Appreciates any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$sce` service. Please look into following link.

[Angularjs Sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: but that is an alternate method. I want to use ngSanitize because it is already used throughout the project.